# How to loop over multiple groups while holding one value constant per group?

Tags: python, for-loop

I am trying to automate a `for loop` calculation within 34 different groups. I have a dataset which contains X and Y points for 400 districts located in 34 provinces. For each province, I want to calculate the distance from that province's district capital to each of the province's districts.

Then, I want to repeat the calculation on the next province's district capital and its districts.

What I have already tried is extremely rudimentary and does not come close to automating the intended results.

```
import pandas as pd
import mpu
### my basic coding ability would lead me to do something like this 34 times,
### manually hunting for the index with the capital and concating results

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rocketfish88/democ/master/af-districts.csv')

new_df = df[0:27]
distance = []
for i in range(new_df.shape[0]):
    distance.append(mpu.haversine_distance((new_df['Y'][7], new_df['X'][7]), (new_df['Y'][i], new_df['X'][i])))
```

#### Here is how I ended up solving this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import mpu

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rocketfish88/democ/master/af1.csv')

j = []
for i in range(399):
    j = df[df['Capital'] == 1][['Y', 'X', 'Province', 'District', 'Capital']]

j.rename(columns={'Y': 'CapY', 'X': 'CapX'}, inplace=True)

df1 = df.merge(j, how = 'left', on = ['Province']) # this is it!

container = []
for i in range(399):
    container.append(mpu.haversine_distance((df1['Y'][i], df1['X'][i]),
                                            (df1['CapY'][i], df1['CapX'][i]))) # working?

container = pd.Series(container)
df1 = pd.concat((df1, container.rename('distance')), axis = 1)
```

#### Although if anyone is still watching,

I could use some help figuring out why this loop works:

```
container = []
for i in range(399):
    container.append(mpu.haversine_distance((df1['Y'][i], df1['X'][i]),
                                            (df1['CapY'][i], df1['CapX'][i])))
```

And this loop does NOT work:

```
for i in range(399):
    df1['distance2'] = ''
    df1['distance2'][i] = mpu.haversine_distance((df1['Y'][i], df1['X'][i]),
                                            (df1['CapY'][i], df1['CapX'][i]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the structure of your data frame, it is a bit tough to give detail.  But, what you have described is a nested loop operation.  in pseudo-code you:

```
Loop over all of the provinces:
  identify the capital somehow
  Loop over all of the districts:
    calculate the distance (capital, district)
```

With the size data you describe, this should be really fast.

I would think it would be easier to not try to do this in a data frame.  It is much easier to understand what is going on.

edit:  To get the pairings of the provinces and capitals out, you could do something like this:

```
df_caps = df[df['ADM2ALT1EN'] == 'Centre'][['ADM1_EN', 'ADM2_EN']]
```

This will make a subsetted data frame with only 2 columns in it, which I think are the ones you want.  Then you can convert that to a list of tuples to make the iteration easier:

```
cap_pairs = [tuple(x) for x in df.caps.values]
```

Now you have something that is easy to iterate with...

```
for province, cap in cap_pairs:
    # do something
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem I am running into, is the way I identify capitals and districts. It wont work in a loop. I identify this issue here: `# Any thoughts on why this does not work?`

Comment: Adding followup to the main entry. I figured it out in probably a very ham-fisted way, but I appreciate your comments as it helped me think about it differently.